# How to customise directions path rendering in OsmAnd?

Tags: osmand

OsmAnd+ 2.3.5

Is there a way of modifying the look of the directions path? There is too much going on there to my liking so I would like to:

- remove the yellow arrows (not sure what they signify but they obscure the road names)
- remove the black arrows (they are less intrusive but still obscure road names)
- change the colour and transparency of the purple path

[image: Directions obscuring every single street name]

Answer (score 1):

It still remains a mystery to me where the black arrows are hiding but I found a way to address the two other requirements.

First I went through a [renderers primer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37495185/779449) which prepared me nicely for the task at hand. Once completed the solution turned out to be quite simple, albeit a bit hackish. I also made the fat purple route a little slimmer. For completeness, here is the entire renderer consisting mostly of my comments:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<renderingStyle name="Decluttered directions path" 
    depends="default" defaultColor="#ffffff" version="1">

    <renderingAttribute name="route">
        <!-- for some details on 'whatever_DIGIT' named attributes see: -->
        <!--
            https://github.com/osmandapp/Osmand

            OsmAnd/src/net/osmand/plus/render/OsmandRenderer.java
            OsmAnd-java/src/net/osmand/render/RenderingRuleStorageProperties.java
            OsmAnd-java/src/net/osmand/render/RenderingRuleProperty.java
        -->
        <!-- strokeWidth="a:b" -> a initial value, b extra when zooming -->
        <!--
            route described by:         color and width
            skinny arrows described by: color_3 and width_3
            black arrows described by:  ?
        -->
        <!-- first two hex digits of a colour specify opacity: 48 ~= 30 % -->
        <!-- disabling skinny arrows by setting opacity to 0 -->
        <case color="#4800cd0a" strokeWidth="10:8" 
            color_3="#00ffde5b" strokeWidth_3="7:6"/>
        <!-- set it up in a similar fashion for the night mode:
        <case nightMode="true" color=.../>
        -->
    </renderingAttribute>

</renderingStyle>
```

And the before/after pictures:

[image: Before - way too much going on here...]
[image: After - almost there, just those pesky black arrows...]